AssertionError for tianshou reinforcement learning
I have been learning tianshou reinforcement learning and meet the assertion error, but I don't know what is the problem is? This is the error.
code error
type here
发生异常: AssertionError
exception: no description
  File "C:\benchmark\SAC.py", line 187, in main
    result = offpolicy_trainer(
  File "C:\benchmark\SAC.py", line 216, in <module>
    main(get_args())
AssertionError:

This is the SAC offpolicy_trainer code.
result = offpolicy_trainer(
            policy,
            train_collector,
            test_collector,
            args.epoch,
            args.step_per_epoch,
            args.step_per_collect,
            args.test_num,
            args.batch_size,
            stop_fn=stop_fn,
            save_best_fn=save_best_fn,
            logger=logger,
            update_per_step=args.update_per_step,
            test_in_train=False
        )

This is the main function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(get_args())

This is the get_args() function.
def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # common
    parser.add_argument('--task', type=str, default='AaaS')
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=0)
    parser.add_argument('--reward-threshold', type=float, default=None)
    parser.add_argument('--buffer-size', type=int, default=1000000)
    parser.add_argument('--epoch', type=int, default=1000)
    parser.add_argument('--step-per-epoch', type=int, default=1) #100
    parser.add_argument('--step-per-collect', type=int, default=1) #1000
    parser.add_argument('--repeat-per-collect', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--update-per-step', type=float, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=512)
    parser.add_argument('--hidden-sizes', type=int, nargs='*', default=[256, 256])
    parser.add_argument('--wd', type=float, default=1e-4)
    parser.add_argument('--gamma', type=float, default=0.95)
    parser.add_argument('--n-step', type=int, default=3) #3
    parser.add_argument('--training-num', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--test-num', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--logdir', type=str, default='log')
    parser.add_argument('--log-prefix', type=str, default='default')
    parser.add_argument('--render', type=float, default=0.01)
    parser.add_argument('--rew-norm', type=int, default=0)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--device', type=str, default='cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    parser.add_argument('--resume-path', type=str, default=None)
    parser.add_argument('--watch', action="store_true", default=False)

    # for sac
    parser.add_argument('--actor-lr', type=float, default=1e-4)
    parser.add_argument('--critic-lr', type=float, default=1e-3)
    parser.add_argument('--alpha-lr', type=float, default=3e-4)
    parser.add_argument('--tau', type=float, default=0.005)
    parser.add_argument('--alpha', type=float, default=0.05)
    parser.add_argument('--auto-alpha', action="store_true", default=False)
    args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]
    return args

What could be the problem here and how could I solve it?
